# How to dismiss action sheet when touch out side action sheet?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I used following method to use actionsheet programmatically with xcode 6, but I don't have idea to show and dismiss it, any one help me on this ..

```
var actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Title Text", message: "Message Text", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

 actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

 self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -2):

This will allow users to cancel the alert. I'm not quite sure how to allow users to tap anywhere outside of the modal. You could possibly use a tap gesture recognizer on the base view, but I think the modal would probably steal those touches.

This should help to get you started on the right track.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select action", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

// First action
let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "First action", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
  (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) in
    println("First action selected")
})

// Cancel action
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) in
  alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
})

alertController.addAction(firstAction)
alertController.addAction(cancel)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: dismissViewControllerAnimated is not a part of UIALertController

Comment: @apmartin1991 I'm probably wrong, but I think UIAlertController might be subclass of UIViewController and UIViewController has dismissViewControllerAnimated starting from iOS 5.

Comment: You were pretty much right, just wrong syntax
[ alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)];

My apologies